# What restrictions would Paul have been preaching against in Colossians 2?

Tags: colossians

> [**Colossians 2:20-23 (ESV)**](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=colossians%202:20-23&version=ESV)
>
> <sup>20</sup> If with Christ you died to the elemental spirits of the world, why, as if you were still alive in the world, do you submit to regulations— <sup>21</sup> "Do not handle, Do not taste, Do not touch" <sup>22</sup>( referring to things that all perish as they are used)—according to human precepts and teachings? <sup>23</sup> These have indeed an appearance of wisdom in promoting self-made religion and asceticism and severity to the body, but they are of no value in stopping the indulgence of the flesh.

What specific restrictions were popular at the time and prompted Paul to preach against them?

Comment: I recommend Douglas Moo's discussion of the Colossians heresy in his commentary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Short answer

Paul has heard from Epaphras of beliefs the Colossians held which got in the way of their relationship with God.  We can't know very much about them beyond what Paul says about them because there isn't anything else recorded about them.  At most, we can speculate.

### Long answer

Paul starts his letter praising the Colossians for their faith and love.  Colossians 1:7-8 ([ESV](http://www.esvbible.org/Colossians+1/)):

> ... just as you learned it from Epaphras our beloved fellow servant. He is a faithful minister of Christ on your behalf and has made known to us your love in the Spirit.

But he quickly moves to acknowledging that they are immature in terms of knowledge—especially when it comes to [*praxis*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Praxis_%28process%29).  Colossians (1:9-10 [ESV](http://www.esvbible.org/Colossians+1/)):

> And so, from the day we heard, we have not ceased to pray for you, asking that you may be filled with the knowledge of his will in all spiritual wisdom and understanding, so as to walk in a manner worthy of the Lord, fully pleasing to him, bearing fruit in every good work and increasing in the knowledge of God.

What follows ([Colossians 1:15-23](http://www.esvbible.org/Colossians+1/)) is perhaps the most laudatory description of a person ever recorded.  Jesus is placed front and center before the reader as the very key to coming before God holy and blameless.  Then Paul shifts to his own work, which is to make the mystery of Christ known to the Gentiles via (in part) his writings.  He defines the mystery several ways including: "the knowledge of God's mystery, which is Christ, in whom are hidden all the treasures of wisdom and knowledge." (Colossians 2:2-3 [ESV](http://www.esvbible.org/Colossians+2/))  For Paul, it seems clear, any practice that is not informed by an understanding of Christ is, at the very least, suspect.

Here's a list of things Paul warns against in the order he references them:

- plausible arguments (2:4)
- philosophy (2:8)
- empty deceit
- human tradition
- elemental spirits of the world
- questions of food and drink (2:16)
- festivals
- new moon [celebrations]
- Sabbath [observance]
- asceticism (2:18)
- worship of angels
- visions
- sensuous minds
- elemental spirits (2:20)
- regulations
- human precepts and teachings (2:22)

And that doesn't include the more dense list in [3:5-8](http://www.esvbible.org/Colossians+3/).  Nor did I include the warning against those who would compel circumcision in [2:11-14](http://www.esvbible.org/Colossians+2/).  If the Colossians knew of Paul's letter to the Galatians or had heard the teaching it contains, they would also be aware of Paul's conflict with those who insisted on Jewish traditions.

Looking at the list of things that Paul warns about, you start to get the impression he's using a shotgun approach—blasting away at anything that might be causing problems in the Colossian community.  We can categorize some of these as Jewish traditions and some as Greek philosophy.  Greek polytheism was likely present as well.

A slightly more speculative suggestion is that Paul is warning against Pythagorean [dynamism](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/05222a.htm).  What strikes me is the the phrase translated as "the elemental spirits" comes from the Greek word *stoicheion* <[4747](http://classic.net.bible.org/strong.php?id=4747)>, which is from the same root as the title of Euclid's [*Elements*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_Elements).  Pythagoras established an esoteric [philosophy](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/pythagoras/#Pyt), which was informed by his mathematical work, that may have been the basis for some 2<sup>nd</sup> century Gnosticism.  He has been credited with a wide range of beliefs including mysticism, [metempsychosis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metempsychosis), religious observances, asceticism and so on.  So it could very well be that Paul has heard that the Colossians have become involved with Pythagorean cosmology.

In any case, Paul stands against all sorts of *praxis* of the old self and encourages unity in Christ.  Colossians 3:9-11 ([ESV](http://www.esvbible.org/Colossians+3/)):

> Do not lie to one another, seeing that you have put off the old self with its practices and have put on the new self, which is being renewed in knowledge after the image of its creator. Here there is not Greek and Jew, circumcised and uncircumcised, barbarian, Scythian, slave, free; but Christ is all, and in all.

Answer (score 1):

I realize that I am alone in this but I'm convinced that John and Paul used KOSMOS not to refer to "the whole world" or even "the Roman empire" but to temple-centric Judaism.

If we understand KOSMOS as "Judaism" it becomes clear what Paul is on about:

> Colossians 2:20-23 English Standard Version (ESV)
>   20 If with Christ you died to the elemental spirits [principles] of the world [Judaism], why, as if you were still alive in the world [Judaism], do you submit to regulations— 21 “Do not handle, Do not taste, Do not touch” 22 (referring to things that all perish as they are used)—according to human precepts and teachings? 23 These have indeed an appearance of wisdom in promoting self-made religion [ceremonies] and asceticism and severity to the body, but they are of no value in stopping the indulgence of the flesh.

This runs completely parallel to this:

> [Mar 7:15-16 KJV] 15 There is nothing from without a man, that entering into him can defile him: but the things which come out of him, those are they that defile the man. 16 If any man have ears to hear, let him hear.

Paul's words to the Galatians become meaningful and lucid when we understand KOSMOS as "Judaism":

> [Gal 4:1-31 KJV] 1 Now I say, [That] the heir, as long as he is a child, differeth nothing from a servant, though he be lord of all; 2 But is under tutors and governors until the time appointed of the father. 3 Even so **we, when we were children, were in bondage under the elements of the world [Judaism]**: 4 But when the fulness of the time was come, God sent forth his Son, made of a woman, made under the law, 5 To redeem them that were under the law, that we might receive the adoption of sons. 6 And because ye are sons, God hath sent forth the Spirit of his Son into your hearts, crying, Abba, Father. 7 Wherefore thou art no more a servant, but a son; and if a son, then an heir of God through Christ. 8 Howbeit then, when ye knew not God, ye did service unto them which by nature are no gods. 9 But now, after that ye have known God, or rather are known of God, **how turn ye again to the weak and beggarly elements, whereunto ye desire again to be in bondage? 10 Ye observe days, and months, and times, and years. 11 I am afraid of you, lest I have bestowed upon you labour in vain.**

Was Paul's concern related to "regulations" and "ascetics" and "days and months..." from the secular world? No, he was dealing with Jews who insisted on gentile observance of the Torah AND Oral Tradition!